# How write SQL script for report with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with data, where I should build report with hard conditions. I attached two screens where I show conditions.

```
ID  TRX     TYPE    INTEREST    DATE
1   C00001  AR      150         01-JAN-2019
2   C00001  YR      220         02-JAN-2019
3   C00001  AR      310         03-JAN-2019
4   C00001  AR      175         04-JAN-2019
5   C00002  YR      45          03-JAN-2019
6   C00002  YR      86          04-JAN-2019
7   C00002  YR      36          05-JAN-2019
8   C00002  AR      89          06-JAN-2019
9   C00003  AR      100         03-FEB-2019
10  C00003  YR      128         04-FEB-2019
11  C00003  AR      69          05-FEB-2019
```

I need the result as -

```
ID  TRX     TYPE    INTEREST    DATE
1   C00001  AR      150         01-JAN-2019
2   C00001  YR      220         02-JAN-2019
3   C00001  AR      220         03-JAN-2019
4   C00001  AR      220         04-JAN-2019
5   C00002  YR      45          03-JAN-2019
6   C00002  YR      86          04-JAN-2019
7   C00002  YR      36          05-JAN-2019
8   C00002  AR      36          06-JAN-2019
9   C00003  AR      100         03-FEB-2019
10  C00003  YR      128         04-FEB-2019
11  C00003  AR      128         05-FEB-2019
```

i.e. assign the interest of last YR to all AR coming after YR.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need a select statement only, Below SQL would work for you -

```
SELECT O.ID, O.TRX, O.TYPE, COALESCE(N.INTEREST, O.INTEREST), O.DATE
FROM DATAA O
LEFT JOIN (SELECT D1.ID, D1.TRX, D1.INTEREST
      FROM DATAA D1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) ID, TRX
                  FROM DATAA
                  WHERE TYPE = 'YR'
                  GROUP BY TRX) D2 ON D1.ID = D2.ID
                                   AND D1.TRX = D2.TRX) N ON O.TRX = N.TRX
                                                          AND O.ID > N.ID
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e83bc693d0ea156fe025e9cd72ad0ce) is the fiddle for your reference.

Comment: @mehman967, Does this work for you?